# Changing file permission of a linux directory in install4j

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, install4j

I am new to install4j and am trying to change the file permission of a directory to 0750 on a project that I inherited. I am in the Define Distribution Tree screen, right click on the directory, select Edit Entry, and change the Unix mode to 750. I save the project. After running the new install (running as root), the file permission is set to 755 (default). Are there additional steps required? I looked for other spots where the file permission may have been explicitly set, but did not find any. Any ideas on what I did wrong and how to debug this? Thanks.

Comment: The permissions will only be set for the directory itself, not for the contained files. I would suggest to look at the file .install4j/installation.log in the installation directory, it shows what permissions are applied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked in installation.log but did not see any permissions being set for the directory.

Comment: If you locate the directory name in the file .install4/i4jparams.conf, what value does the corresponding "mode" attribute contain?

Comment: I decided to go global and changed the Default Unix file mode and Default Unix directory mode in File Options to 770 for both. However, the directories and files are still the "normal" permissions, that is, 755 for directories and 644 for files. What am I missing?

Comment: The i4params.conf file show 755 (directory) and 644 (files), such as "<dir name="webapps/name1" mode="755" />"  I thought setting the Default Unix file/directory mode would change this.

Comment: Please send your install4j project file, the .install4j/installation.log file and the .install4j/i4jparams.conf file to support@ej-technologies.com